# MYSQL comparing multiple values in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

How can I compare multiple values in Left join ?

I have two tables

```
table a
id val
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   a

table b
val fullform
a    apple
b    banana
c    cat
```

I would write,

```
select a.id, b.fullform from a left join b on a.val=b.val
```

I assume it will join on a=a or b=b

I want to compare like this,

```
select a.id, b.fullform from a left join b on a.val in (a,b)
```

is it possible without writing it in `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
select a.id, b.fullform from a left join b on a.val = b.val
where a.val in (a,b)
```